# showing decimal numbers in Excel graph

Tags: excel, graph

i need to put the decimal numbers starting with 0,... to the Excel graph. If I create the graph and add the values my decimal values is still 0,00 at the graph. If I change them (ex. 400) the graph works good!

adding the screenshots.

[decimals numbers starting with 0,..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FugVU.png)

[graph with normal numbers works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8sGH.png)

Comment: Are the decimal numbers really formatted as numbers or as text? If they are perceived as text they will run along the x axis at y = 0.

Comment: yes, they are..

Comment: how are you changing them when you say  change them (ex. 400)?

Comment: you click on the cell with amount and replace it with 400 for example.

Comment: I still think they might be interpreted as text. Has the decimal been changed as described here https://superuser.com/questions/550834/values-with-decimal-point-do-not-appear-on-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue! I posted (.) behind the zero and It has to be (,).

Comment: See my last comment! It is seen as text.